# Application Pool Displaying GUID Instead of Name

Tags: application-pool

I have been creating service applications in SharePoint 2010 manually, not using the wizard. Can you tell me if this is really the behavior? Is it possible to rename it and if yes, is it advisable?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Check [Get the corresponding SharePoint services name of the Application Pool GUID](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/18/get-the-corresponding-sharepoint-services-name-of-the-application-pool-guid/)

Answer (score 1):

Please do not rename your application pools nor change any of its binding properties. SharePoint interacts with IIS internally and its recommended not to make changes to the application pool property changes manually. Let SharePoint handle that. At the most, you can choose to manipulate your recycling schedules for application pools used by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

It is OOTB and normal behavior of SharePoint.

It is not suggested to rename any of this application pool. It can break your service applications.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was under the impression that these application pool names should display the name, i thought i was doing something wrong during creation of service applications.

Answer (score -1):

You can correlate the GUID to the Name by using powershell and notate that somewhere, say, in a SharePoint list!

Comment: Can you please be more detailed in how to execute PowerShell to get the correlation. Your answer is not super helpful right now :)

Comment: This is a bit old, but [this blog post](http://spnotes1.blogspot.com/2012/10/find-application-pool-name-from-guids.html) outlines how to use PowerShell. In case it disappears, the command is Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | select Id, Name